# What is the history behind the present day geology of California? What processes took place that led to the formation of each region as shown in fig?

Tags: geology, tectonics, structural-geology, california

[image: California Geomorphic Provinces]

This is the image showing the different geomorphic provinces of California. What led to the formation of these provinces, and what events took place that resulted in the diverse geological setting of California.

Comment: it is expected that you do some research before asking a question here on our site,it is best if you ask a more spesific question because the geological history of california is a too large subject to cover in one answer.you can take a look here to learn more about this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geology_and_geological_history_of_California